# C# reflection datatype

Tags: c#, optimization, reflection

I would like to optimize the below code The only difference is the datatypes RadioButton, Label, and Button. Outside the method I have an loop that iterates over all the controls in the aspx-page.

```
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
...
public partial class MyUserControl : UserControl
...
if (control is RadioButton)
{
    try
    {
        (control as RadioButton).Text = SPContext.Current.Web.Locale.LCID == 1033 ?
        DataBinder.Eval(keys.en, control.ID).ToString() :
        DataBinder.Eval(keys.sv, control.ID).ToString();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        (control as RadioButton).Text = "Key not found: " + control.ID;
    }
}
else if (control is Label)
{
    try
    {
        (control as Label).Text = SPContext.Current.Web.Locale.LCID == 1033 ?
        DataBinder.Eval(keys.en, control.ID).ToString() :
        DataBinder.Eval(keys.sv, control.ID).ToString();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        (control as Label).Text = "Key not found: " + control.ID;
    }
}
else if (control is Button)
{
    try
    {
        (control as Button).Text = SPContext.Current.Web.Locale.LCID == 1033 ?
        DataBinder.Eval(keys.en, control.ID).ToString() :
        DataBinder.Eval(keys.sv, control.ID).ToString();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        (control as Button).Text = "Key not found: " + control.ID;
    }
}
```

Comment: _"I would like to optimize the below code"_ = [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: Moved question to: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/221049/c-reflection-optimize-out-type

Answer (score 1):

One way to reduce duplicate code is to use a `text` variable, and assign that to `control.Text` afterwards.

```
string text = "";
try
{
    text = SPContext.Current.Web.Locale.LCID == 1033 ?
    DataBinder.Eval(keys.en, control.ID).ToString() :
    DataBinder.Eval(keys.sv, control.ID).ToString();
}
catch (Exception)
{
    text = "Key not found: " + control.ID;
}

if (control is RadioButton) {
    (control as RadioButton).Text = text;
} else if (control is Label) {
    (control as Label).Text = text;
} else if (control is Button) {
    (control as Button).Text = text;
}
```

If you are using C# 7 or above, you can make use of pattern matching:

```
if (control is RadioButton rb) {
    rb.Text = text;
} else if (control is Label lbl) {
    lbl.Text = text;
} else if (control is Button btn) {
    btn.Text = text;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can significantly simplify your code by using `dynamic`.

Since `ID` is defined in the base class, but `Text` is defined in all of the concrete classes but not in the base.

```
dynamic myControl = control;
try
{
    myControl.Text = SPContext.Current.Web.Locale.LCID == 1033 ?
    DataBinder.Eval(keys.en, control.ID).ToString() :
    DataBinder.Eval(keys.sv, control.ID).ToString();
}
catch (Exception)
{
    myControl.Text = "Key not found: " + control.ID;
}
```

You can add a guard clause for the types at the beginning:

```
if (!(control is RadioButton || control is Label || control is Button)) return;
```